# How to use MCP73831 with multiple voltage sources correctly?

Tags: diodes, charger, voltage

I'm trying to use an MCP73831 with multiple voltage sources (one is from a 24VDC to 5 VDC regulator, the other one is from a standard USB) but I'm having a bit of a problem.

For the moment, I'm only trying without connecting both voltage sources at the same time, but I tested with the both sources independently.

The problem appears at my status pin when I want to recharge my battery. When the battery is fully charged, the status PIN seems locked and it never reaches its assumed voltage (5V).

This is my circuit (the filtering capacitors are not shown in this schematic, but I added it according to the value specified in the datasheet to do my test):
[image]

Here is the value of the stat PIN of the MCP73831 with a fully charged battery (yellow signal = stat pin, purple signal = VBAT).

[image]

Everything else is working fine (charge, regulator) except the value of this stat pin. It seems it will never go to it's high state (VDD = 5V). It stays at this voltage forever.

When I remove the D21 or the D22 diode, the problem completely disappears and I obtain the good response (yellow signal = stat pin, purple signal = VBAT):
[image]

I thought it could be caused by the voltage drop of the diode but I still have 4.75V at the VIN Pin. It's normally enough to make the MCP73831 working (from the datasheet, the minimal VIN is 3.75V) and the 3.3V regulator (from the datasheet minimum of 3.3V, 3.80V at the VIN PIN).

What could do such response?

How could I use the MCP73831 with multiple voltage sources if I can't use the diode to "separate" these voltage sources?

I'm pretty sure I can't use the two voltage sources at the same time if I'm removing the diodes (D21 & D22) but maybe I'm wrong?

**Edit 1 :** @Cisco25 : 
[image]
I removed the NMOS22 section from the STAT pin, there is my result with the diode (yellow signal = stat pin, purple signal = VBAT): I didn't see it at first, but the signal is not stable in terms of frequency on this test.

[image] 
[image]
[image]

Again if I remove the diode, I obtain the same result than previously (a constant VDD=5V signal as the battery is charged).

**Edit 2 :** 
Thank's to Cisco25, I identify the problem was still there without all the transistors and the 3.3V regulator.

There is my exact circuit, I really don't know why with the diode the status pin stay "in charge" with the led turned on.

When I remove the diode and replace it by a single wire, I got the right VDD value on the stat pin.

When I short-cut the diode, I got the same problem, like if my diode had still an influence on the circuit.

Is it possible that my problem comes from the fact my diodes are Zener ?

There is the schematic : 
[image]

Status pin in yellow, battery voltage in purple **with the zener diode** :
[image]

Status pin in yellow, battery voltage in purple **without the zener diode** :
[image]

**Edit 3 :**

I modified the schematic as you said :
[image]

It worked correctly this time :
[image]

What is the problem doctor ? :-/

Comment: No you can't remove the diodes without the risk of back-powering the lower 5V rail. You do have the 4.7uF capacitor recommended on VBAT output, correct? STAT pin is directly driven by VDD in high-state and conditioned by the battery charging state (eg. VBAT), have you monitored the VDD and VBAT pin in these conditions? Do you have any ripple or unexpected value?

Comment: *"the filtering capacitors are not shown in this schematic, but I added it according to the value specified in the datasheet to do my test"* Please do show them in the schematic(best option), or at least, describe which cap you used where and what value.

Comment: @Cisco25 Yes, I have a 4.7uF capacitor on the VBAT (@Huisman I will add the missing capacitors on the schematic ASAP, it's standard ceramic capacitors described on page 1 of the MCP73831 datasheet). I have tested all parts of the circuit independently and it worked correctly.The battery is correctly charging and stay at it's maximum value of 4.2V. Same thing for the VDD. It is constant to 4.75V the all time.

Comment: @A.Girafe Have you disconnected RGATE23 from the STAT pin? Why is the NMOS22 circuit wired this way? The 4.7us off-time in the STAT pin oscilloscope capture shot is strangely similar to the time constant of the RC discharge of RTIRAGE24 and CI/O21 (5us).

Comment: @Cisco25, I disconnected the RGATE23 from the stat Pin, I got the same result (I added it on my question). I put an NMOS22 circuit to take the charge status information on my uC (not connected for these test) that accept only 3.3V.The status pin can be as High as the VDD input so 5V. I tried without the whole RGATE23 section of the circuit (including the mostfet and the capacitor you mentioned) and got the same result.

Comment: @A.Girafe "I got the same result" -> It's actually different, the new waveform you posted has a different frequency (14kHz vs 25kHz), duty cycle (~50/50 vs 12/88), and low-level voltage of 720mV (compared to 640mV previously). Could you please post your full schematic? With the decoupling capacitors, the 5V upstream circuits, etc. Is there anything else connected to the STAT signal? Also can you please post oscilloscope shots of VDD and VBAT when that happens? To see if we're not missing anything there.

Comment: @Cisco25 I updated the schematics and the pictures. For now, the 5V upstream  comes only from the 24V to 5V converter. There is nothing plugged in the 5VDC_ (USB). The 24V to 5V converter is powered by my stabilised power supply. There is nothing more connected to the stats pin than what is represented on the schematic :-/. I don't know why, but disconnecting the NMOS22 circuit part make the stat pin voltage instable...

Comment: @A.Girafe I think the STAT pin behavior is related to instability in the rest of the circuit. Do you have capacitance on +5VDC rail? If it's kept floating, it may act as a resonator. Can you disconnect the PMOS21 circuit from the VBAT rail, moving the jumper between J22 pin2 and 3? The PMOS21 is mounted reversed I believe, you want the source to be on the VBAT side. Repeat the test when the 3.3V regulator is exclusively powered by 5V (and not the battery). Then remove D23 and check what happens when 3.3V is powered-off. You may want to do this test with VBAT too so we can strike-off the 3.3V

Comment: I have no extra capacitance on the 5VDC rail. I test it with one 10uF tied to ground but it doesn't change the signal at all :-/. In fact the 5VDC Rail is constant with and without the capacitor. I will test all of that tomorrow, but i'm not sure, when you say "remove D23", you mean cut the circuit or replace it by a single wire ?

Comment: @Cisco25 Thank's to your help, I identified it wasn't about the transistors nor the regulator. The PMOS was in fact correctly wired for my tests but I don't know why I put it in the reverse way on the intial schematic. I simplified the schematic since the problem is still there without these parts. (see edit 2). I still don't understand why this diode as such influence on the MCP73831 stat pin :- /

Comment: @A.Girafe I am very interested in troubleshooting problems like this myself so happy to help :) Good circuit isolation, that helps a lot narrow it down. Just FYI, this is a Schottky diode, not Zener. Now can you connect the Schottky's cathode to RLED21, disconnect VDD input from RLED21 and connect VDD directly to +5VDC_24V?

Comment: @Cisco25 It worked ! I added the schematic and the result (edit 3). I don't really know how to conclude about this ^^' Also, I checked, I'm using zener diode (BZX79-B/C2V4) for this test instead of the Schottky diode of the schematic. I'm not sure about the difference between the two models but I will probably use Schottky diode at the end of the day.

Comment: @A.Girafe Well, this experiment was half the way, you still want the diode connected to VDD input too, to use dual 5V source. I did not realize you were using the Zener diode instead of Schottky, that is the real problem. Zener diodes have completely different usage and are intended to be used as voltage sources rather than in OR-ing circuits. The 0.7V and 2.1V alternating voltages steps on STAT are surely introduced by the Zener. Please try the Schottky instead and verify everything is functional :)

Comment: @Cisco25 I just found some Schottky diode, tested it and everything worked just fine ! I don't know why there is such differences between this two kind of diode but it made it worked ! Thank's A lot !!! Also, I removed all the resistors of the Mosfet gate during my tests, it worked just fine but maybe I should put them back ? I'm not sure about their utility and about their values :- / Thank's a lot again !

Comment: @A.Girafe Great to hear :) Tip for me next time: inquiry more about those components in question (I just looked up the diodes part number and they look fine to me). For you: make sure not to omit any change to the shown circuit ;)

Comment: @A.Girafe I don't think you really need the gate resistors in your circuit unless you anticipate having a greater voltage than the gate can handle then it'd come handy for placing a divider on the gate

Comment: Thank's a lot for your help and advices @Cisco25  !!!